# Cancel the upcoming UIAlertView after leaving current viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Here's the thing.

I got AVC popviewcontroller to BVC, I got some UIAlert releated events, It would show at any time.

The problem is that sometimes when I've already navigated back to the AVC, here comes the Alert. But It shouldn't be shown in the AVC.

How can I cancel all the alert about to show queue, to avoid it shows in AVC?

Here's what I've thought. How about I set `self.alertController = nil` in `viewWillDisappear` method? would this work?

Update--------
I got a device connected with my APP via wifi, when wifi disconnect, I got the notification, so I let the UIAlert show with one action, which is 'back to AVC', apparently I don't want this Alert shows in AVC, but sometime it would. I did some code like `dispatch_global` and `put alert in`main_queue`, could this be the problem?

--code

```
//BVC.h
@interface BVC : CVC

//BVC.m
//BVC:CVC   B is implement from C, actually the alert show event in CVC
//get notification from somewhere
- (void)deviceDisconnected {
    [self showAlertViewWithMessage:DeviceNotFoundWord];
}


//CVC.h
- (void)showAlertViewWithMessage:(NSString *)message;

//CVC.m
- (void)showAlertViewWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    [ProgressHUD dismiss];
    if (!self.alertView) {
        self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:title otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [self.alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: on which OS you are running this code?

Comment: iOS8/9 only， no need to consider 7 or below 7

Comment: what do you mean by UIAlert related events??

Comment: You have to add this line of code: `sdhfsdhjbvhjsbd = @"sdjsnjdnjsvnj";`  On a more serious note, if you provide no details on how these alerts are triggered, nor show any relevant code, you aren't going to get a useful answer, except by sheer luck.

Comment: @AjinkyaPatil see my update, thanks